# Correct structure of a comparative-type sentence with dependent clauses

Tags: comparatives, dependent-clause

The original sentence says:
"The greater the amount of total suspended solids the higher the turbidity of the water."

I think it feels off because it lacks a verb. Would the following be an acceptable edit, and does there need to be a comma before "then"?
"The greater the amount is of total suspended solids then the higher the turbidity is of the water."

I'm struggling because this sounds like two dependent clauses with no independent clause present. I would appreciate any advice or explanation. I have been staring at this sentence too long!

Update: Is an implied verb acceptable in formal writing? Is a comma required?
For those who have answered or will answer, thank you!

Comment: The original sentence is correct. Find the rules here : http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/themore.html

Comment: @Eilia: I'm not sure how relevant that link is, because all the examples do have verbs: _shook_, _rose_, _saw_, and _looked_.

Comment: @Nicole, You're right, another example : The greater the amount of water the greater the shrinkage and its related higher suction... (www.stastier.co.uk/nhl/topics/mineralogy.htm)

Comment: possible duplicate of ["The more, the merrier!" -- Is this a sentence? If not... what?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/210487/the-more-the-merrier-is-this-a-sentence-if-not-what) Where the accepted answer says *It's a sentence with an implicit verb*. In OP's example, that would be, for example, *The greater the amount of total suspended solids **is**, the higher the turbidity of the water **is**.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, but I think this explication needs to be in an answer somewhere, since comments eventually disappear (and not everyone reads all the comments).

Comment: @FumbleFingers And it's probably worth noting that, unless there are implied verbs, these are not clauses, just phrases.

Comment: @bib: If you define a "clause" as consisting of a subject and predicate (or require it to include a verb) then I guess [*The more the merrier*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+more+the+merrier%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) doesn't contain any clauses. But a "sentence" is usually said to consist of one or more clauses, so by that logic it's not a sentence either. But [I am sceptical](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/12859/) about the "usefulness" of this kind of categorization in contexts like this.

Comment: Note that @bib said "implied verb".  I think his argument is that one of two conditions exists.  Either there is no verb, in which case the model is a set of phrases and a fragment, or there is at least one implied verb, in which case the model does contain at least one clause and might stand as a complete sentence.  For what it's worth, I agree.  When I read the original, my mind automatically supplies a couple of parallel verbs.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But your skepticism in the linked discussion seems to focus on the distinction between two clauses making up one or two sentences. The concept of subject/predicate helps organize thought and clarify expression. Without insisting on slavish compliance, leaning toward clauses and sentences as a structural tools seems helpful.

Comment: @bib: Well, I'm guessing the OP here isn't a native speaker, and *in this specific context* it seems to me the attempt to "categorize" the cited construction is decidedly *unhelpful*, since it's leading him to doubt the "correctness" of a commonplace usage. Just as it seems silly for writers who should know better to suppose they ought to include a comma in *The more, the merrier* simply because that comma would in fact be useful if the two equated "elements" (whatever you want to call them) had been significantly longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there are implicit verbs, it certainly should be acceptable to make them explicit.   I consider the sentence to be equivalent to:

> The greater the amount of total suspended solids [is], the higher the turbidity of the water [ is / must be / will be / should be / becomes / ... ].

Even with explicit verbs restored, there is no dependent clause in the sentence.   There are two independent clauses.   The first independent clause represents a condition, the second represents a consequence.

It is common but not necessary to express the relationship between condition and consequence with a subordinate clause.   Two independent clauses can serve the same purpose, especially when supported by the relationship between the clauses' modalities.

If you do wish to represent the conditional relationship using a dependent clause, I recommend eliminating the inversions and using the word "if" to make the conditional clause subordinate:

> If the amount of total suspended solids is greater, the turbidity of the water is higher.

The original sentence contains a number of unusual features.   The clauses are inverted.   The copular verbs are elided.   The coordination is asyndetic.   In spite of all of that, this type of sentence can be found in formal writing.   I would expect a comma to mark the asyndetic coordination, but I otherwise find the original sentence to be unsurprising.