# "The bigger, the better"

Tags: grammar, etymology, syntactic-analysis

What is the function of "the" in these kinds of phrases? It cannot be the definite article.

Can someone analyze this? It's common and definitely standard but seems to elude any grammatical explanation.

Comment: Example: "The more you read, the more you know."  How would you diagram/parse a sentence like this? I don't even know where to start.

Comment: This expression contains two vestigia from Old English: 1) the definite article being used in the instrumental case (which denotes the means by which something occurs), and 2) correlating *th-* conjunctions where we would use a *wh-* conjunction (Old English speakers said *then I get home from work, then I go to sleep* instead of *when I get home from work, I go to sleep*). It's just an old way of saying *as it gets bigger it gets better* that has somehow refused to kick the bucket.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [“The more, the merrier!” — Is this a sentence? If not… what?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/210487)

Comment: You should edit your question and include the example that you left in a comment. People do not always read comments when they see a question they can answer.

Answer (score 7):

"Bigger" and "better" are the comparatives of adjectives, but simply juxtaposing them will confuse English speakers because they are going to look for a noun to take the modifiers:  "a bigger better burger."

One workable locution separates the words with a **copulative verb**:

> Bigger **is** better.

Now you've got an easy parse of Subect-Verb-Complement, and "bigger" will be understood to be a noun in the figurative sense of "state of being bigger" or "the bigger ones as a class."

Your example keeps the juxtaposition (sans verb) by marking the comparatives' nominal usages with the **definite article** as a determiner.

> **The** bigger, **the** better.

This is a general idiomatic usage.  If X and Y are adjectives, and C(x) and C(y) are their comparatives, then

> The C(x), the C(y)

means

> The C(x) one/ones is/are C(y) than C(~x) one/ones.

where ~x means the opposite of x.  Let's try it with another example:

x = "small"
~x = "large"
C(x) = "smaller"
C(~x) = "larger
y = "fast"
C(y) = faster

> The C(x), the C(y) <-> The smaller, the faster.
>
> The C(x) ones are C(y) than C(~x) ones <-> The smaller ones are faster than the larger ones

The elisions implied by the idiom make it difficult to diagram the idiomatic sentence directly.

Answer (score 4):

When used against a comparative it is an adverb. [Webster's Revised Unabridged 1913](http://www.bibliomania.com/2/3/257/frameset.html) Dictionary has this definition of [The](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=the&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on) Word:

> The, adv. [AS. \'ebē, \'eb\'df, instrumental case of sē, seó, \'ebæt, the definite article. See 2d The.] By that; by how much; by so much; on that account; -- used before comparatives; as, the longer we continue in sin, the more difficult it is to reform. Yet not the more cease I." Milton.
>
> So much the rather thou, Celestial Light, Shine inward, and the mind through all her powers Irradiate. Milton.

In this case it seems to mean "[How much] bigger, [is by how much] better." It  should probably be written "The bigger it is, the better it is." but then it would lose its potent brevity.

Answer (score 1):

(1) *The* in *the bigger, the better* not only can be, but **is** the definite article. There is no other *the* in English.  However, there are many, many uses for the definite article, beside the one the textbooks mention. That's not a definition of the definite article; that's just one of its properties. Mostly articles do odd jobs in English; they don't have meanings or definitions -- they just have functions.

(2) *The bigger, the better* is an example of a Construction in English. It's a shortened version of

- *The bigger it is, the better it is,*

or possibly of

- *The bigger you make it, the better I'll like it*,

or something else along the same lines.

The point is that something has been left out, to be filled in by context and convention,
and if we're not there then, we'll never know what's missing.

The construction itself (it doesn't have a specific name, as far as I know -- there are thousands of these in English; probly "The bigger the better" construction is as good a name as any) has the form

- *the* `comparative phrase or clause`, *the* `comparative phrase or clause`

The comparatives themselves can be just about anything

- *The smaller the Statue of Liberty seems to be, the farther away you are from it.*

The meaning of the construction is to announce a continuous relation between two variables, each changing with the other. The change can be positive, like *the bigger, the better*, or negative, like *the more freebies we give out, the less money we take in*.

(3) The function of *the* in this construction is to mark that it's **this** construction and not a different one.