# Analyzing structure: "as fast as X so faster will I Y"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I am analysing the following:

> I will aid my disciples;
>   as fast as they acquire this balanced power and joy
>   so faster will I push them.

I grasp the general idea that "I will push them" "faster" than "as fast as they acquire".

At first, it seemed to me that the last two parts are clauses closely joined by conjunctions *as* and *so*.

But after contemplating it some more, I'm compelled to read "as fast as (something)" as a verb modifier. Is this the case? Is this fragment a verb modifier for "will push"?

If the last part is a verb modifier, then what is the function of *so*?

How should I parse this?

Comment: It looks like this is the complete text in case that helps anyone who would answer this question: http://www.sacred-texts.com/oto/lib90.htm

Comment: *so* has it’s regular meaning: “in the same manner as”.  If we remove the inversion it becomes: “I will push them faster than [the speed at which] they acquire this balanced power and joy.” Meaning no matter how fast they acquire BP&J, I will push them just a little bit faster.

Comment: Sorry for not posting a link to the full text; I am studying a printed copy.

Comment: It's a poeticalization.  Don't overanalyzitate it.

Comment: @HotLicks unfortunately "overanalyzing" this phrase is one of my current tasks. At the very least, I must find out we are seeing here two coordinate clauses or one clause plus a complicated verb modifier.

Comment: It's a poetic idiom, often used for aspirational scenarios -- "As A as B" identifies a state of affairs (current or potential), "So X will I/we/they Y" identifies a subsequent action.  "So" is arguably a conjunction, but that's about as far as I'd take it.  Poetic structures tend to resist rigid syntactic analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This construction appears a little contrived to me, perhaps because of the attempt of the translator to strike a poetic chord. This would be an equivalent in ordinary Modern English:

> I will aid my disciples
>
> *the faster* they acquire this balanced power and joy,
>
> *the faster* I will push them.

Or:

> I will aid my disciples
>
> I will push them *as fast as they* acquire this balanced power and joy.

But that would be a little mundane. Here is my attempt:

> I will aid my disciples;
>
> *as fast as they* acquire this balanced power and joy,
>
> I will push them.

Comment: So, "as fast as they" functions as conjunction, and the last two clauses are related by subordination?

Comment: I haven't looked at it in detail, but I would say that "as fast" is equivalent to "the faster", and the "so faster" is also equivalent to "the faster". I wouldn't be too concerned about grammatical qualification are these are essentially **idioms** ("a speech form or an expression of a given language that is peculiar to itself grammatically or cannot be understood from the individual meanings of its elements", see American Heritage).   But for terminology you could perhaps start from [this question on stackexchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/267098/the-bigger-the-better).

Comment: But that's not poetry.

Comment: The distinction is not always easy to make. It follows a style of philosophical writings that are "poetically written". There were also philosophical poets like Dante.