# Definite article before "earlier"

Tags: definite-articles

Why there is a 'the' before earlier?

"... demonstrate that **the** earlier someone learns an additional language the more likely they are to master it."

Comment: Hello, Umbesabro. This is a well known type of expression in English (a 'snowclone'). The archetypal example is the stock saying 'the bigger[,] the better'. Neck and neck with 'The more, the merrier.' It's a set pattern.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["The bigger, the better" – What is the function of "the" in these kinds of phrases? It {seems a strange place for a definite article to occur}.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/267098/the-bigger-the-better)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, thank you.