# the comparative ... , the comparative ... and predication

Tags: correlative-comparatives

I know people have asked about the correlative comparative construction, but none of the previous posts concerns its specific analysis.

How would you analyze the boldfaced part of #2 below?

> 1. The more you buy, **the greater the discounts you receive**.
> 2. The more you buy, **the greater discounts you receive**.

In #1, "greater" stands in a predicative relation to "the discounts you receive"; it's paraphrasable as "The discounts you receive are (the) greater the more you buy.
The copular verb "are" can be treated as omitted in #1.

Does the same predicative relation hold in #2? What about an alternative analysis whereby "greater discounts" stands in a verb-object relation to "receive"? In this connection, consider #3:

> 3. The longer you work, **the more money you earn**.

Which kind of relation holds in #3? A predicative or verb-object relation?

Comment: "Money" is a mass noun.  "Discount" is not.

Comment: That seems to be an irrelevant point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["The more, the merrier!" -- Is this a sentence? If not... what?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/210487/the-more-the-merrier-is-this-a-sentence-if-not-what) I also believe [your earlier question about the same construction on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/173830/) is a duplicate on that site, putting aside the issue of whether *this* one represents undesirable "cross-posting" on the SE network of sites.

Comment: But I'm asking which analysis should be adopted, and there are no satisfactory answers there.